# How to grey out picture in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to grey out a non-active button in bottom app bar, but with colorfilter widget getting grey square with picture. How can I grey out only picture (*.png)

```
return GestureDetector(
      onTap: this.widget.onTapFunction,
      child: Container(
        width: 50,
        height: 55,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ColorFiltered(
                colorFilter:
                    ColorFilter.mode(this.widget.color,                               BlendMode.saturation),
                child:                    Image.asset("assets/icons/${this.widget.iconName}"),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              this.widget.title,
              style: GoogleFonts.lobster(
                fontSize: 14,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

This is the picture:

[image: bottomAppbar]

Answer (score 1):

Replace the ColorFiltered with this:

```
Image.asset(
  'assets/icons/${this.widget.iconName}',
  color: Colors.grey,
  colorBlendMode: BlendMode.color,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ShaderMask? I just saw it today, so I am not sure if this will work on what you need.

https://youtu.be/7sUL66pTQ7Q

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use the `ColorFiltered` widget, just use the `color` property of the `Image` widget:

```dart
Image.asset(
    'IMAGE_URL',
    color: Colors.grey
)
```

Comment: This will paint all the widget so you will see just a grey area with border.

Comment: Just reduce the oppacity of the color.